# Changing Windows 7 installation date

Tags: windows, windows-7

Windows 7 saves its installation date. It can be viewed with

```
cmd /k systeminfo | find "Original Install Date"
```

in the command prompt. How can I change the saved value to a different day?

Comment: Do you intend to rotate(extend) your Trial version for some more time?

Comment: No I don't. I just wanna change the install date =).

Comment: Of course I have. My window's legit if that's why you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The install date is stored in the registry value as UNIX time (32-bit value containing the number of seconds since 1/1/1970)

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InstallDate

[Source](http://blogs.sepago.de/helge/2009/09/24/how-to-determine-the-windows-installation-date-with-and-without-powershell/)